# How to access a JSON object that's already been parsed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I made this code sandbox to explain the issue I'm having. I added comments on the bottom and when you change {buyDate.id} to {buyDate.market_data.current_price.usd}. You'll see the issue I'm having. I believe it's fetched correctly and the console shows what I expect. Here's the code sandbox: [codesandbox.io/s/coingecko-api-example22-9zysm?file=/src/App.js](http://codesandbox.io/s/coingecko-api-example22-9zysm?file=/src/App.js)

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Here is the original post:

I have looked at other answers to similar problems and nothing has solved the issue I'm having. This is ReactJS.

I set the following variables:

```
const [trade, setTrade] = useState({
   sellData: {},
   buyData: {},
 });
```

When I console.log the buyData with the correct input I want, I receive this:

```
buyData: 
{id: "bitcoin", symbol: "btc", name: "Bitcoin", image: {…}, market_data: {…}, …}
community_data: {facebook_likes: null, twitter_followers: 68912, reddit_average_posts_48h: 7.833, reddit_average_comments_48h: 270.833, reddit_subscribers: 1303941, …}
developer_data: {forks: 25238, stars: 42377, subscribers: 3497, total_issues: 5257, closed_issues: 4491, …}
id: "bitcoin"
image: {thumb: "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/thumb/bitcoin.png?1547033579", small: "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/small/bitcoin.png?1547033579"}
market_data:
current_price:
aed: 32711.28293095498
ars: 553792.3126161147
...
```

So, when I call `trade.buyData.market_data.current_price.aed` which should work, I get an error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_price' of undefined` but I want it to return `32711.28293095498`.

I tried changing the set value of trade.buyData from `{}` to other types such as NaN or undefined. I also tried adding catch error messages and nothing is working. At one point, it worked half the time for no reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not seeing any value of `market_data`

Comment: market_data need to be an object as per the above data example. are you missing somethig?

Comment: You don't even have a value specified for market_data

Comment: Be very careful with states and variables. A state is not exactly the same as a variable. When you `setTrade()` the value of `trade` does not immediately change. Also, always remember to make a copy of your `trade` object instead of updating the object directly. Eg. `setTrade({ trade ..., sellData: xxx })` if not you would see weird behaviors. All variables in a React class or function are destroyed each time it finishes rendering. States keep values (not variables) in some temporary storage and reload them the next time you render so it feels like variables but states are not normal js vars

Comment: @slebetman, Yes, I have a fetch function that does this where `setTrade({ ...trade, buyData: jsonData });`. Why would I need to declare `market_data`? Isn't that an object returned by the api and I can just call it with .market_data then .current_price then .aed as shown when I console log it?

Comment: I know it's fetching everything correctly because when I do, trade.buyData.name, it prints "Bitcoin" which is expected

Comment: Are you forgetting that React will render at least ONE time before the `fetch` completes? So at least **once** (if not more) the value of `buyData` will be `{}` because you have set it yourself: `buyData: {},`

Comment: I don't think I gave enough information. I made this code sandbox to explain the issue I'm having. I added comments on the bottom and when you change it. You'll see the issue I'm having. I believe it's fetched correctly and the console shows what I expect. Here's the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/coingecko-api-example22-9zysm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your codeSandbox it's clear that you have a null pointer on `buyData` because you define the object empty and try to access it's property on the render fase (initial render in this case).

You can fix it with [optional chaining operator (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in `market_data` on line 27 of you code sandbox - `buyDate.market_data?.current_price.usd`

```js
return (
    <div className="App">
      <input defaultValue={buyDate} onChange={(val) => handleBuyChange(val)} />
      {/* market_data needs to be null checked */}
      {buyDate.market_data?.current_price.usd}
      <h4>
        The purpose of this project is to input the date and get back the
        bitcoin price at the time
      </h4>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: @shidog12345 happy to help :)